# My Python socket server can only receive one message from the client

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

Hi i got a problem with my socket server or the client the problem is i can only send one message from the client to the server then the server stops receiving for some reason i want it to receive more then one.

Server.py

```
import socket 

host = ''
port = 1010

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host, port)) 
s.listen(1) 
conn, addr = s.accept() 
print ("Connection from", addr)
while True: 
    databytes = conn.recv(1024)
    if not databytes:
        break
    data = databytes.decode('utf-8')
    print("Recieved: "+(data))
    if data == "dodo":  
        print("hejhej")
    if data == "did":
        response = ("Command recived") 
        conn.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
conn.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket 

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1010 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host, port)) 
print("Connected to "+(host)+" on port "+str(port)) 
initialMessage = input("Send: ") 
s.sendall(initialMessage.encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    response = input("Send: ") 
    if response == "exit": 
        s.sendall(response.encode('utf-8')) 
s.close()
```

Comment: The server is sending only after the `while` loop, there is an indentation error: move `conn.sendall(response.encode[...]`1 space right...

Comment: Please, FIX your indentation so we know where the problem resides...

Comment: Ok i have fixed the indentation problem now i think. but i  still got the same output as described in the question. Which is i can only send one message from the client to the server.

Comment: put everything after `s.listen(1)` into a while loop.

Comment: It dident work with putting everything after s.listen(1) into a while loop. I think the problem may lie in the loop its self either in the client or the server. im suspecting that it breaks after the first message is sent from the client.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but the LOGIC of it is wrong, 
in the `Client.py` file and particularly in this loop:

```
while True:
    response = input("Send: ") 
    if response == "exit": 
        s.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

This will not send to your `Server` side anything but string `exit` because of this:

`if response == "exit":`

So you are asking your `Client.py` script to only send anything the user inputs matching the string `exit` otherwise it will not send.

It will send anything at the beginning before this `while` loop since you wrote:

```
initialMessage = input("Send: ") 
s.sendall(initialMessage.encode('utf-8'))
```

But after you are inside that `while` loop then you locked the `s.sendall` to only send `exit` string

You have to clean up your code logic.

Comment: Tnx for your answer.  I have already  figured this out.  The code is working.