# Python Socket Server Can Only Handle 1 Client at a time

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to make a server-client program using threads to handle each client, but the server will only accept one client at a time. If the first client disconnects, then the second client is accepted. Furthermore, each client can only send data once, then the program fails to send any more.

Prior to posting, I have looked at MANY other Stack Overflow posts, including the following:

[how can I make a server communicate with more than 1 client at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172765/how-can-i-make-a-server-communicate-with-more-than-1-client-at-the-same-time)

[python multithreaded server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520821/python-multithreaded-server)

[My Python socket server can only receive one message from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103188/my-python-socket-server-can-only-receive-one-message-from-the-client)

But through looking at these posts I have found no solution.

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
from threading import *


def main():

    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('172.20.3.62', 5000))
    s.listen(1)
    clients = []
    print("listening")

    def clienthandler(c):
        clients.append(c)
        try:
            while True:
                data = c.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    print(data)
                    for client in clients:
                        client.send(data.encode("UTF-8"))
        except:
            clients.remove(c)
            c.close()

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("accepted a client")
        Thread(target=clienthandler(c)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the client code:

```
import socket
from threading import *


def main():
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('172.20.3.62', 5000))
    print("connected")
    def send():
        msg = input("ENTER:")
        s.send(msg.encode("UTF-8"))

    def receive():
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
            if data:
                print(data)
            else:
                break

    Thread(target=send).start()
    Thread(target=receive).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `Thread(target=clienthandler(c))` -> `Thread(target=clienthandler, args=(c,))`

Comment: @Rawing Thanks so much!  You solved it perfectly! Also, I solved the client only sending once, forgot to put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user Rawing. His/Her solution was: Thread(target=clien‌​thandler(c)) -> Thread(target=clien‌​thandler, args=(c,))
This allowed for more than one thread, and I was able to solve the only one message problem by putting the client send block in a while loop.